# How to isolate location of stackoverflow in code?

Tags: c#, stack, stack-overflow

Never thought I'd say this, but I just got a stack overflow in my program (which I have been working on forever without testing). Basically, it's a server, and when the first person connects I get a stack overflow. I've put in breakpoints and I still can't figure out where it's occuring (infinate loop). I thought I'd come to request the people of the site named after my problem to help me fix this.

How can I find (amongst thousands of lines of code) where a stack overflow occurs?

Thanks so much,
Christian

Comment: Well, a ["stack trace"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) would be a good start.

Comment: I believe this is what is called [a title drop](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TitleDrop) :) If you can add the stack trace and some related code to the question we'd stand a much better chance of telling you which lines were causing the problem.  As it is, this question has no other answer than "look at the stack trace", and "it is probably caused by unbounded recursion".

Comment: Not to point out the obvious, but it sounds like you could use some try/catch blocks to help isolate where the problem is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these simple steps to get that which statement causing this error and hang up your application:

1. Make debug point on start point of application and start debugging. After this press
   <kbd>F5</kbd> to check where it taking time and causing Stack overflow.
2. Now go Debug Menu and Select `Break All` or Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> then it will make the focus on that statement which  your application is executing right now.

Another option is Use `Stack Trace`

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi, nice professional answer. I'll try this and accept if it works (and still will accept if nobody else responds with something better).